# Is there a way to spread props over a component without overriding specified attributes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a bunch of base components for an app and I'd like to write as little customization as possible. Instead opting to pass on the attributes of the parent to the child. I have a bunch of buttons that defined like this:

```
export const PrimaryButton = (props) => {
    return (
        <button className={style.primary} {...props}>{props.children}</button>
    )
};
```

However, when I do this, if the button is declared like this:

```
<PrimaryButton className="someClass">Submit</PrimaryButton>
```

the class name on the parent overrides the classname provided in the component. What I'd like is for them to work together. I have figured out that I can do this by declaring the props I want individually like this:

```
export const PrimaryButton = (props) => {
    props.className = props.className + style.primary;
    return (
        <button className={style.primary + props.className}>{props.children}</button>
    )
};
```

Since I'm no longer spreading things over though I now have to declare anything like onClick manually and this seems messy because I don't know what events it may need to have in the future and I'd like it to be as reusable as possible without needing to be changed all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [destructuring with rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to separate the `className` and `children` from the props you wish to spread:

```
export const PrimaryButton = ({ className = '', children, ...props }) => (
  <button className={`${style.primary} ${className}`} {...props}> 
  {children}
  </button>
);
```